# MySQL: Select last updates from two really different tables

Tags: mysql, select

I tried to search everywhere, but not found any answer.

I have two different tables in database with only two same columns (name, dateChanged) and really many others which are different in both tables. I wish to get latest X updates from both tables (in future from more tables) but I cannot find the way to do it. I mean something like

```
SELECT `name`, `dateChanged` FROM `mpolymer`, `mmetal` ORDER BY `dateChanged` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

to show quick summary of newest activities. I tried UNION, JOIN, but all of these need to join on some common column, which is not possible (I think). Do you have any possibilities to do what I wish to do, please?

Comment: Show sample data and the desired result. It is unclear (to me) whether you want X rows from `mpolymer` AND X rows from `mmetal` or if you want a total of X rows where it does not matter how many come from each table.

Comment: I can't figure this out - do these tables have relationships with one another or not?  If so, why won't a JOIN work?  If not, why would you want their data combined into a single query anyway?

Comment: wait, I am finding way to show rows, cannot paste here, one row from each table is too long for comment...

ah, here: http://jsfiddle.net/fn89S/

What I need is to get names of last updated materials from all (at this time two) tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the last X events across both tables (not X events from one and X events from the other), this should work for you.

```
SELECT name, dateChanged FROM mpolymer
UNION
SELECT name, dateChanged FROM mmetal
ORDER BY dateChanged DESC limit 10;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8f3/1)

To also show the table name (based on your comment)…

```
SELECT name, dateChanged, 'mpolymer' AS tableName FROM mpolymer
UNION
SELECT name, dateChanged, 'mmetal' AS tableName FROM mmetal
ORDER BY dateChanged DESC limit 10;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8f3/3)

Comment: Ah, very thanks, i forgot to second select in my tryings - SELECT `name`, `dateChanged` FROM `mpolymer` UNION `name`, `dateChanged` FROM `mmetal` ORDER BY `dateChanged` DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: Hi, I have only last question. Now I have all last updates i need, but when I am working with them, I need to know from which table it comes. I am using data through $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); like $name = $row['name']; But what is tha way I can get table name (some rows comes from mpolymer, some from mmetal)?

Comment: finally i have solution with extra table collumn with same table name for every row in table. I don't know if it's the greatest solution, but it works. :-)

Comment: @SilentCry No, that's not the greatest solution :) See my update.